# Who is the Seventh Sin?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I recently watched the anime but in the end I couldn't remember who the seventh sin was. He was shown as Escanor in the first episode (about 4:43). Is it possible that he isn't showing up in the anime? Or is he impersonated by someone else?

Comment: You don't need to have the series title in your question title.

Comment: I made some edits for grammar. If I've changed the meaning of something, feel free to edit things back in.

Comment: the seventh sin is will be shown in the second series (if there is one)

Comment: what are everyone's sins? they never actually explained what they all did...

Comment: @anonymous That would be a good question. [Ask it!](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nanatsu-no-taizai)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably by the seventh member, you mean Escanor because he was not introduced in the anime primarily. However, if you pay attention closely, he appears in the last OVA of the Seven Deadly Sins. At 23:46 in the OVA 4, Escanor appears outside a cave carrying a barrel. He will be quite active in the recently announced sequel Seven Deadly Sins 2.

The members of the Seven Deadly Sins along with their Symbol, Animal Spirit and their super powers are as follows:

- **Meliodas**, The Dragon's Sin of Wrath **(Dragon, Full Counter)**
- **Diane**, The Serpent's Sin of Envy **(Serpent, Creation)**
- **Ban**, The Fox's Sin of Greed **(Fox, Snatch & Immortality)**
- **King**, The Grizzly's Sin of Sloth **(Bear, Disaster)**
- **Gowther**, The Goat's Sin of Lust **(Goat, Invasion)**
- **Merlin**, The Boar's Sin of Gluttony **(Boar, infinity)**
- **Escanor**, The Lion's Sin of Pride **(Lion, Sunshine)**

Here is a pic of the seven members for your reference:

[image: Seven Deadly Sins, names, title and symbol]

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The Seven Deadly Sins consist of:

- **Meliodas**, The Dragon's Sin of Wrath
- **Diane**, The Serpent's Sin of Envy
- **Ban**, The Fox's Sin of Greed
- **King**, The Grizzly's Sin of Sloth
- **Gowther**, The Goat's Sin of Lust
- **Merlin**, The Boar's Sin of Gluttony
- **Escanor**, The Lion's Sin of Pride

Escanor is the one that doesn't appears in the anime. He's revealed in a special side story in the manga called the **Vampires of Edinburgh**. If I recall right, the location of Escanor is unknown which is why he didn't appear in the anime